# Как изменить формат получаемых даннных

Tags: javascript, java, ввод

Сейчас тут получают данные в формате: дата.месяц. Как изменить просто на год?

```
public String getSignByDate(String date) throws RemoteException {
    System.err.println(date);
    if (date.length() != 5) {
        return "Invalid date format";
    } else {
        Integer day = Integer.parseInt(date.substring(0, 2));
        Integer mounth = Integer.parseInt(date.substring(3));

        String sign = this.getSign(day, mounth);

        return "sign is " + sign;

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если продолжать парсить дальше то следующем значением будет год

```
Integer year = Integer.parseInt(date.substring(6));
```